# How to use People Picker in CSOM?

Tags: people-picker, csom

I am doing Console project to get data from SharePoint using CSOM. I want to use **People-picker**. I using following code but it returns nothing. Can anyone help?

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.ClientPickerQuery.ClientPeoplePickerQueryParameters query = new Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.ClientPickerQuery.ClientPeoplePickerQueryParameters();
            query.AllowEmailAddresses = true;
            query.MaximumEntitySuggestions = 50;
            query.PrincipalType = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.PrincipalType.All;
            query.PrincipalSource = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.PrincipalSource.All;
            query.QueryString = "username";  
            query.WebApplicationID= new Guid("3a9bf856-9541-4bd0-a0e7-8bb5e9357327");
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientResult<String> result = Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.ClientPickerQuery.ClientPeoplePickerWebServiceInterface.ClientPeoplePickerSearchUser(context,query);
```

Comment: In Console application you want a control??

Comment: No. I just need list of users for the query string

Comment: you mean, you need all users from active directory/your site?

Comment: yes, users retrieved as searching in people-picker in my site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake. I didn't pull value from the "ClientResult collection". After adding result.Value it returned response.

This code is working fine for SP2013 and SharePoint Online. But **not working in SP2010**. Any one have idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

The People Picker in SharePoint 2013 has had a bit of a face-lift.
The ‘Verify Address’ and ‘Address Book’ icons are gone and what’s left is a cleaner, simpler interface.
But new controls means that some of the older approaches to working with the People Picker no longer work.
As usual I’m working with SharePoint 2013 on the client side (CSOM) working with JavaScript and jQuery.

[image: peoplepicker using CSOM and jquery]

Refrence :
[peoplepicker using CSOM and jquery](https://jasonscript.wordpress.com/2013/08/07/javascript-and-working-with-the-sharepoint-2013-people-picker/)

Note : Blog is not mine , i have refereed  it in past and i have got output as i want.

Comment: I am using C#(CSOM). but this blog post is about using Javascript Object Model

Comment: @Mani OK. .  I'll  get  back  to  shortly  regarding  c#(CSOM)